# How to force an environment variable to a certain value inside phpunit test?

Tags: php, phpunit, environment-variables

In my phpunit I have this configuration:

```
<php>
    <env name="ENVIRONMENT" value="test"/>
</php>
```

I worked under the false assumption that it always would set the environment variable to the value `test`. Yet when the system already has the variable set, then it prefers the already existing value.

```
$ export ENVIRONMENT=GNARF
$ phpunit -c test/phpunit.xml
```

So inside the tests the value of `env('ENVIRONMENT')` will be `"GNARF"` even though I expected `"test"`.

Is there a way to make phpunit to treat the `env` setting not as a default but rather as the definite value it should be using?

I also would like to avoid calling phpunit in a certain way just to get the right env variables.

So while this works:

```
ENVIRONMENT="test";./vendor/bin/phpunit -c tests/phpunit.xml
```

I rather configure it inside the `phpunit.xml` file if possible.

Comment: The value is also ignored when running the tests with PhpStorm. (Tested with PHP 5.6.24 and PHPUnit 5.7.0)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This way worked for me (tested with **PHPUnit 6.5**):

```xml
<phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="MyProject">
            <directory>tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <php>
        <env name="API_KEY" value="fakeApiKey" force="true" />
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Here's the [pull request](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/pull/2723) where they added this new feature (in case you're interested).

> sebastianbergmann added this to the PHPUnit 6.3 milestone on 4 Jul 2017

Comment: This is still relevant for PHPUnit 9.5.10.

Answer (score 3):

The environment variables are set in `PHPUnit_Util_Configuration::handlePHPConfiguration()` and indeed, it looks like this:

```
foreach ($configuration['env'] as $name => $value) {
    if (false === getenv($name)) {
        putenv("{$name}={$value}");
    }
    if (!isset($_ENV[$name])) {
        $_ENV[$name] = $value;
    }
}
```

As it seems, there is no way to circumvent this check without unsetting the variable first. And while you're at it, you could as well set it to the desired value immediately.

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence: "And while you're at it, you could as well set it to the desired value immediately." What do you mean?

Comment: Instead of `ENVIRONMENT=` to unset the value so that the XML takes effect, I would directly use `ENVIRONMENT=test`, that's all.

Comment: I am currently thinking about going the bootstrap way as pointed out by @gontrollez and teir set them to the value I like.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `env` vars from the `bootstrap` file. The bootstrap file can be selected from the `phpunit.xml` file so the result would be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Create:
`.env.testing`

Add: `APP_SOMETHING=123`

Open:
`phpunit.xml`

Add:
`<server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made it inside Laravel\Lumen. I want to test the behavior of the code in different environments:

```
private function provideData(): array
{
    return [
        'tc_1'    => ['production', 'in', 'in'],
        'tc_2'    => ['development', 'in', 'str'],
        'tc_3'    => ['testing', 'in', 'str'],
    ];
}

/**
 * @dataProvider provideData
 * @return void
 */
public function testProvidedData(string $env, string $inStr, string $outStr)
{
    $_ENV['APP_ENV'] = $env;
    $this->assertSame($outStr, Class::method($inStr));
}
```

In Class::method() the code looks like:

```
public static function method(string $inStr): string
{
    return (env('APP_ENV') === "production")
        ? $inStr
        : 'str';
}
```